# Weird glitch when scale and blur an image in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm experimenting a "zoom and blur" css effect. So when I hover over an image, it's supposed to blur out and scale a bit, while contained in a div with `overflow:hidden`.

However, when running in Chrome, there's always a weird glitch. A blurry white border shows up around the container while the transition is going.

I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing it? Or a method of circumventing it? Thanks a lot!

You can see a gif demonstrating the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3a8W.jpg

And the same code running in firefox as a comparison: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1008t.jpg

Note the borders within the image.

And below is my code:

```
<style>
#img0{
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
}
.hoverBlur{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
.hoverBlur:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
    transform:scale(1.1);

    -webkit-filter:blur(15px);
    -moz-filter:blur(15px);
    filter:blur(15px);

}
.container{
    margin:200px;
    width:500px;
    height:333px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <img id="img0" src="test.jpg" class="hoverBlur"/>
</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/urur6byy/

Comment: It looks like it's not a glitch, but more like unclarified behaviour. I think the image is blurring with relation to the outside background colour (white) so the blur near the edge of the image is being mixed with the colour assumed to be underneath the image. I've no idea how to work around it though.

Comment: For your image, try give it an invisible padding border. I'm guessing chromes blur algo doesn't handle edge cases except by assuming white for the over edge sampling (or the zoom + blur causes this to happen). You can then just mask the extra padding by putting a "frame" over the top of it.

Comment: GibboK's jsfiddle shows it well, note how the bottom edge of the image behaves. so what you can do is set a background colour of transparent to the image element, maybe that will help?

Comment: @Martin you're right, the border comes from a mixture of the background color. Not the background color of image though, but that of its container. Seems like the border is generated by any kind of cropping. If I resize the window to cut half of the image, it will show up at the end of the window frame too. I still believe it's a bug, since it goes away once the transition is over, and firefox has no problem with it whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

This is a *REALLY* old thread but I ran into this issue and couldn't find the solution published anywhere else so I'm posting it here:

You can fix this by adding a margin to the image that is the same size as the blur size (in this case 15px) then transform: translating the image back into place.

https://jsfiddle.net/zeojxtvb/

So in our example, a blur(15px) is applied to the image. So also apply the following to the image:

```
img {
    ...
    margin: 15px;
    transform: translate(-15px, -15px);
}
```